# Barycenter correction for inner planets in solar system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations, planets, solar-system

I want to run simulations of the solar system, and I've read in some papers that to speed up the simulations it is useful to use the barycenter correction of the inner planets (from Mercury to Mars), and just add to the simulation the major planets (from Jupiter to Neptune). I don't know how to do that and I was wondering if there is any way to compute it in a easy way.

Any suggestion?

thanks a lot for everyone! =)

Comment: "some papers" -> which papers? And I think the answer to your questions depends entirely on why you want to simulate the SS.

Comment: Here you have an example, page 2 "dinamical simulations" : http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01586v2.pdf